# Chef: aws load_balancer_options stickiness

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, amazon-elb

I am able to create an internal elb with chef provisioning using following code sample:

```
elb_options = [{

      protocol: :http,
      port: 80,
      instance_protocol: :http,
      instance_port: 80,
    },
    ...
]

load_balancer "elb_name" do

    machines "machine_name"
    load_balancer_options listeners: elb_options,
    subnets: ["subnets"],
    scheme: 'internal'
    action :create
end
```

I am trying to figure out how do I pass options to enable the 'load balancer generated cookie stickiness' for a certain expiration period.
I went through AWS/Chef documentation but was not able find what I was looking for.
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

assuming it's going through: https://github.com/chef/chef-provisioning-aws

Under the hood it's using the AWS Ruby, SDK so the options should match options that you would pass in when creating an ELB via the SDK. See here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ElasticLoadBalancing/Client.html#create_load_balancer-instance_method

The gist of it is that setting the stickiness is done separately from creating the load balancer.

Read through: 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/elb-sticky-sessions.html

So it's a separate call that's made to the load balancer with the right policy define to make it act as sticky. Bad news is that it does not seem to be supported by the chef aws provisioning code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Mircea,
Did you mean there is no straight forward way to do using chef provisioing... or we cant do it at all using chef provisioning.

Comment: you cannot do it via the chef-provisioning-aws. you probably need to write your own recipe / make separate calls to the AWS Api to set the stickiness policy